# How to wrap all strings in a project with a macro / function?

Tags: c++

Ok so I have a string encryption thing that goes`XorStr( "" )`.

How can I put this on all strings without doing them one by one?

Comment: Why don't you post what have you wrote, instead of ask the community to write code for you? ;)

Comment: i'm not, i'm asking how to put code around every single string in a project...

Comment: Xor != encryption

Comment: What do you want to achieve? All your unencrypted strings will anyway be included in a binary file.

Comment: @user8885290 Could you specify what actually are you  trying to do? Starting to look like an XY problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact, that "Find and Replace" functionality also provides support for regular expressions. Thus, you may easily find all strings, capture them and wrap with `XorStr()`.

In "Find" field, `((\".+?\")|('.+?'))` will  match all strings with double or single quotes. If you want only the double-quoted, reduce this to `(\".+?\")`.

In "Replace with" field, use: `XorStr($1)`.

Comment: That was my fist thoguht too. Does this regex support nested strings? `"he said \"Hello, world\""`

Comment: @Mawg no, these will throw the matcher off. And raw string literals too, of course.

Comment: thanks, one issue, it can't find what I'm searching